# R different arguments for the same S4 method applied to different classes

Tags: r, dataframe, methods, constructor, r-s4

I have just started working with S4 objects and I would like to achieve something that with S3 seems really straightforward, but I cannot figure out how to do it with S4 classes.

With S3, by using `UseMethod()` is really easy to create a constructor which behave differently depending on the classes of the inputs, for example:

```
.Foo <- function(...) UseMethod(".Foo")

.Foo.character <- function(x, y, z) {
    y <- as.factor(y)
    structure(data.frame(y, z, x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
        class = c('Foo', 'data.frame'))
}
.Foo.numeric <- function(x, ...) {
    .Foo(x = as.character(x), ...)
}
.Foo.data.frame <- function(df) {
    do.call(what = .Foo, args = df[, c('x', 'y', 'z')]) 
}
```

And this way, given a data frame we can apply `.Foo()` on it and get an object of class `Foo`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = c(2,2,3,3), z = 5:8)
tmp <- .Foo(df)
str(tmp)
```

Which prints:

```
Classes ‘Foo’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "2","3": 1 1 2 2
 $ z: int  2 3 4 5
 $ x: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Now, trying to do the same using S4 I have:

- First create a Foo class:

```
setOldClass("data.frame")
Foo <- setClass("Foo",
          contains = "data.frame"
         )
```

- Then we create a generic `.Foo`:

```
setGeneric(".Foo", function(x, ...) standardGeneric(".Foo"))
```

- Lastly we create the methods for it:

```
setMethod(".Foo", signature("character"), function(x, y, z) {
    y <- as.factor(y)
    Foo(data.frame(y, z, x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
})
setMethod(".Foo", signature("numeric"), function(x, ...) {
    .Foo(x = as.character(x), ...)
})
setMethod(".Foo", signature("data.frame"), function(x) {
    do.call(what = .Foo, args = x[, c("x", "y", "z")])
})
```

After `str(.Foo(df))` we get:

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
Formal class 'Foo' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 4 slots
  ..@ .Data    :List of 3
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 2 levels "2","3": 1 1 2 2
  .. ..$ : int  2 3 4 5
  .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"
  ..@ names    : chr  "y" "z" "x"
  ..@ row.names: int  1 2 3 4
  ..@ .S3Class : chr "data.frame"
```

So this approach works. Now my question and problem is: is this done correctly? If I want to have as an argument for .Foo.data.frame `df` instead of `x`, can I do it? Or I cannot because all the first inputs must have the same name as the defined in the Generic? Can I somehow do something like:

```
setGeneric(".Foo", function(x, df, ...) standardGeneric(".Foo"))
setMethod(".Foo", signature("character"), function(x, y, z) {
  y <- as.factor(y)
  Foo(data.frame(y, z, x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
})
setMethod(".Foo", signature("numeric"), function(x, ...) {
  .Foo(x = as.character(x), ...)
})
setMethod(".Foo", signature(x = "missing", df = "data.frame"), function(df) {
  do.call(what = .Foo, args = df[, c('x', 'y', 'z')])
})

.Foo(df)
```

But this fails with the error

```
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘.Foo’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "missing"’
```

Thanks in advance! Sorry if I overextended or if I explained things incorrectly but is my first time working with S4 and I cannot find information but really simple one.

Comment: I don't think "missing" qualifies as a "class". --and-- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/dotsMethods.html  ... says ---> 'Beginning with version 2.8.0 of R, S4 methods can be dispatched (selected and called) corresponding to the special argument “...”. Currently, “...” cannot be mixed with other formal arguments: either the signature of the generic function is “...” only, or it does not contain “...”. (This restriction may be lifted in a future version.)'

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your errors is due to argument matching.

```
.Foo(df)
```

is interpreted as

```
.Foo(
  x=df,
  df=(missing),
  ...=(empty list)
)
```

This is what R is trying to tell you when it returns the signature `(data.frame, missing)` --- it looked for a method for signature `(foo, missing)`, didn't find one, tried the superclasses (i.e. `data frame`) and didn't find a method for that signature either.

If you want to specify the *object* `df` as the *argument* `df` then you can either name it explicitly

```
.Foo(df=df)
```

or use positional matching:

```
.Foo(,df)
```

both of which should work for you.